# Segmentation fault : g_ptr_array_foreach

Tags: c, glib

Task 3: I am using g_ptr_array_foreach to print the GPtrArray ... As per to me..this is how we do it.. but still I am getting segmentation fault.. Please.. Any insight fellow peers? :)

```
/************************************************************************************************************
*       FILE NAME       :       ex-garray-7.c
*
*       DESCRIPTION     :       demonstrates implementation of pointer arrays i.e GPtrArray
*
************************************************************************************************************/


#include<stdio.h>
#include<glib.h>

#define SUCCESS 0

/************************************************************************************************************
*       FILE NAME       :       main
*
*       DESCRIPTION     :       allocates memory to pointer array, pointers point to strings 
*
*       RETURNS         :       SUCCESS
*
***********************************************************************************************************/

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

/**********************************NEW LEARNING************************************************************
- all glib functions are perfectly alright
- */

//gpointer ret_val = NULL;

/* GPtrArray is designed to hold pointers, 
  - no need to specify  particular type when    creating it or adding    and indexing elements. */

/******************************REQUIRED DECLARATIONS*******************************************************/

// declare GPtrArray pointer variable
GPtrArray* ptrarr = NULL;


/********************************REQUIREDD INITIALIZATIONS*************************************************/

// allocate memory to GPtrArray using   g_ptr_array_new(); 
ptrarr = g_ptr_array_new(); /* No argument while allocating memory to array of pointers


/*********************************PERFORMING REQUIRED TASKS************************************************/

/* 1. add string hello to it using
    g_ptr_array_add(
                      GPtrArray* array,
                      g_strdup(<"string">)); */
g_ptr_array_add(
                ptrarr,
                g_strdup("Let's"));

// 2. add other strings like I love C and gpointers too
g_ptr_array_add(
                ptrarr,
                g_strdup("Use"));

g_ptr_array_add(
                ptrarr,
                g_strdup("GLib"));


g_ptr_array_add(
                ptrarr,
                g_strdup("\n"));


/* 3. print entire GPtrArray using 
    void g_ptr_array_foreach(
                                 GPtrArray* array,
                                 GFunc function,
                                 gpointer user_data); */
g_ptr_array_foreach(
                    ptrarr,
                    (GFunc)printf,
                    NULL);

printf("\n Removing the third element i.e index is 2");

/* 4. remove the third element using 
   gpointer g_ptr_array_remove_index(
                                        GPtrArray* array,
                                        guint index_
                                        ); */
 g_ptr_array_remove_index(ptrarr, 0);



/* 5. remove the new 3rd and 2nd element
    gpointer g_ptr_array_remove_range(
                                        GPtrArray* array,
                                        guint index_,
                                        guint length
                                      ); */
g_ptr_array_remove_range(ptrarr, 0,1);

// 6. print the new GPtrArray
printf("\n pointer array now is \n ");
g_ptr_array_foreach(
                    ptrarr,
                    (GFunc)printf,
                    NULL);

// 7.  print the first item in GPtrArray
printf("\n The first element in the GPtrArray is %s ", g_ptr_array_index(ptrarr, 0)/* same as g_array_index*/);

// 8.  free the memory
g_ptr_array_free(ptrarr, TRUE); // same as g_array_free
return SUCCESS;

}
```

is there some other way as well, to print the elements of the GPtrarray?

Answer (score 3):

The second argument to the glib `foreach` functions must match the following prototype:

```
void funcname (gpointer data, gpointer user_data);
```

`printf` does not match that prototype. If you remove the cast in `(GFunc)printf` the compiler will tell you this. It is not a good idea to use casts to hide messages telling you what the bug is in your code.

Consequently, you need to use a wrapper function:

```
g_ptr_array_foreach (ptrarr, print_cb, NULL);

static void
print_cb (gpointer data,
          gpointer user_data)
{
  printf ("%s\n", data);
}
```

Or, better yet, just do the loop inline to make things clearer and save the overhead of calling the callback many times:

```
for (gsize i = 0; i < ptrarr->len; i++)
  {
    const gchar *element = g_ptr_array_index (ptrarr, i);
    printf ("%s\n", element);
  }
```

Comment: oh.. I guess I need to explicity write my printf() function somewhere in the program.. am I write sir?

Comment: You need to make a function matching that prototype, that might invoke printf inside it. I would recommend consulting an example program that uses these glib functions

Comment: Hi there, sir, I just found out that if we want to print our elements we can use something like - 

g_slist_foreach(list, (GFunc)printf, NULL);

infact if I need to free all my elements in my g_slist, I need to give something like -
g_slist_foreach(list, (GFunc)g_free, NULL);

the built in functions like printf and g_free are invoked with the item in the data.

May be , glib version being used is not the latest one...

Comment: There are not many questions regarding GLib here?.. Do developers don't use it that much?

Comment: `GSList` is a completely different data structure from `GPtrArray`. You can’t use `g_slist_*()` methods with a `GPtrArray`.

If you want to free all elements in an actual singly-linked list, use `g_slist_free_full()` rather than `g_slist_foreach()` and `g_slist_free()`, since that will only iterate over the list once, rather than twice.

Lots of developers use GLib.

Answer (score -1):

From **glib** reference document, the *prototype* is:

```
g_ptr_array_foreach (GPtrArray *array,
                     GFunc func,
                     gpointer user_data);
```

Your code is almost correct. Instead of casting `printf`, try to use `g_print`

```
g_ptr_array_foreach(
                    ptrarr,
                    g_print,
                    NULL);
```

Comment: `g_print()` behaves the same as `printf()` and will suffer from the same problems. This is not the right answer.